# JsPath.json.update doesn't work with array element in the path (IdxPathNode)?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-json

Are my eyes deceiving me or can I not update a nested node with a JsPath containing an array element in between? (e.g. /a/b(0)/c)

```
val pnJson = Json.parse("""{"a": {"b": [ {"c": { "d": 1 } } ] } } """)                                     
val pnJsPath = (__ \ "a" \ "b")(0) \ "c"                                                                   
val pnTrans = pnJsPath.json.update ( __.read[JsObject].map{ _ ++ Json.obj( "e" -> 2 )} )

pnJson.transform(pnTrans)
```

//result: **java.lang.RuntimeException: expected KeyPathNode**

If I cant use __.json.update, How can I accomplish this?  *Trying to accomplish this with immutablity.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is [you can't do that with `JsPath`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/943). That ticket mentions using the [JsZipper](https://github.com/mandubian/play-json-zipper) library as a better way to manipulate JSON. If you choose to use it, you can do:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json.extensions._
import play.api.libs.json.extensions._

scala> import play.api.libs.json.monad.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.monad.syntax._

scala> val pnJson = Json.parse("""{"a": {"b": [ {"c": { "d": 1 } } ] } } """) 
pnJson: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"a":{"b":[{"c":{"d":1}}]}}

scala> val pnJsPath = (__ \ "a" \ "b")(0) \ "c" 
pnJsPath: play.api.libs.json.JsPath = /a/b(0)/c

scala> pnJson.update(pnJsPath, _.set(__ \ "e" -> JsNumber(2)))
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"a":{"b":[{"c":{"d":1,"e":2}}]}}
```

Otherwise, your best bet is to break your task into two parts, the first part being parsing the array and the second part being transforming it into a new array with modified contents.

Comment: +1 for insisting the Play people add this to their library rather than relying on JsZipper :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness of the thread, the later versions seem to permit manipulations just fine, e.g. pruning with arrays on the way. An example below:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
val j = Json.parse("""{"name":"Test","towns":[{"twn":{"id":1,"status":["A","B"]}}, {"twn":{"id":2,"status":["B"]}}, {"twn":{"id":3,"status":["B","C"]}}]}""")
val t = (__ \ "towns").json.update(
          Reads.list(
            (__ \ "twn" \ "id").json.prune
              ).map(JsArray(_)))
j.transform(t)
```

There are some issues if one of the array objects would not contain "id" but in most circumstances this will do the job.